# Creating (or passing) a string from a pipe

Tags: c++, c

Alright, I'm working on a "simple" project of using forks and piping to search a file for the number of occurrences of a given word. The program is to fork the process in a manner where the parent sends a word at a time to the child for the child to then search through a file and sum up the occurrences of the passed word. My issue is that I'm not familiar with C++ and therefore am having a hard time figuring out how to get the string out of the pipe. The program is currently passing the words through the pipe, but they are only coming out as a long line of characters at run time. Can anyone provide some examples or tips for retrieving as a string and not individual characters? Here is my code as of now:

```
int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {

fstream fileWell ("well.txt");
fstream fileWords ("words.txt");

int pipefd[2];
int counter = 0;
pid_t cpid;
char buf;
const char * sentWord;
string toCheck;
string toSend;

pipe(pipefd);
cpid = fork();

if (cpid == -1) {
    cout << "ERROR" << endl;
    exit(1);
}

if (cpid == 0) {
    close(pipefd[1]);
        while (read(pipefd[0], &buf, 1) > 0)
            write(1, &buf, 1);
        cout << endl;
        write(1, "\n", 1);
}

else {
    while (getline(fileWords, toSend)) {
        close(pipefd[0]);
        sentWord = toSend.c_str();
        write(pipefd[1], sentWord, strlen(sentWord));
    }
    close(pipefd[0]);
    toSend = "-1";
    sentWord = toSend.c_str();
    write(pipefd[1], sentWord, 3);
    close(pipefd[1]);
    wait(NULL);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
return 0;
}
```

I feel like I know what to do once I've gotten the string, but I can't really move forward without that part. Thank you for any suggestions or help.

Comment: No need to `close(pipefd[0])` multiple times. Also, you’ll need to split into words at some point, and you should send some separator on the pipe – maybe the child then can simply use `getline`?

Answer (score 2):

Pulling out the unused data and concentrating on just the purpose of your functional code, I'm fairly certain the following was what you were at least trying to accomplish. Some things that were addressed.

- Input file stream not opened unless on parent process only.
- Fixed multiple closures on pipe handles.
- Use `std:string` members for data pointers and length calculation
- Ensure the string terminator was sent as part of the data package.
- Treat a terminator on the child as a signal to finish the string.

What you do with the words you receive is up to you. I adapted this to simply send them to standard out before resetting. I feel you likely have alternate plans, but that is somewhat unrelated to the question.

See below. Adapt as needed:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

#define READ_FD     0
#define WRITE_FD    1

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int fd[2];
    pid_t cpid;

    pipe(fd);
    if ((cpid = fork()) == -1)
    {
        cout << "ERROR" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    // child process
    if (cpid == 0)
    {
        // don't need the write-side of this
        close(fd[WRITE_FD]);

        std::string s;
        char ch;
        while (read(fd[READ_FD], &ch, 1) > 0)
        {
            if (ch != 0)
                s.push_back(ch);
            else
            {
                std::cout << s << '\n';
                s.clear();
            }
        }

        // finished with read-side
        close(fd[READ_FD]);
    }

    // parent process
    else
    {
        // don't need the read-side of this
        close(fd[READ_FD]);

        fstream fileWords ("words.txt");
        string toSend;
        while (fileWords >> toSend)
        {
            // send word including terminator
            write(fd[WRITE_FD], toSend.c_str(), toSend.length()+1);
        }

        // finished with write-side
        close(fd[WRITE_FD]);
        wait(NULL);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Test**

The word file I sent through this was Billy Shakespeare's monologue from As You Like It, Act II, Scene VII. The beginning and ending of the output appear below:

```
All
the
worlds
a
stage
And
all
the
men
and
women
merely
players
....
oblivion
Sans
teeth
sans
eyes
sans
taste
sans
everything
```

---

**Alternative: A Custom Stream Buffer**

An alternative (and perhaps what you're really looking for) is to adapt a stream buffer that can be married to a `std::istream` to use on the client side similarly to regular stream io. The simplest example I can muster, a one-char-buffer streambuf, appears below:

```
// adapt a single char streambuf for an input stream
class ifd_streambuf : public std::streambuf
{
protected:
    int  d_fd;
    char d_buffer[1];

public:
    ifd_streambuf(int fd) : d_fd(fd)
    {
        setg(d_buffer, d_buffer + 1, d_buffer + 1);
    };

private:
    int underflow()
    {
        if (read(d_fd, d_buffer, 1) <= 0)
            return EOF;

        setg(d_buffer, d_buffer, d_buffer + 1);
        return *gptr();
    }
};
```

Utilizing this, the client process code segment from the previous source listing can be adapted to simply following:

```
ifd_streambuf fdbuf(fd[READ_FD]);
std::istream inf(&fdbuf);

std::string s;
while (inf >> s)
    std::cout << s << '\n';
```

which is considerably more the style of C++ you're likely accustom to.  The server side would need to change as well, appending any whitespace as the word-separator:

```
while (fileWords >> toSend)
{
    write(fd[WRITE_FD], toSend.c_str(), toSend.length());
    write(fd[WRITE_FD], " ", 1);
}
```

It would take extra work to adapt this streambuf to buffer more than a single character (some extra housekeeping stuff), but I leave that for you to discover.